# Implement slider, to use AJAX to call a web method and dynamically create HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Below is my requirement but I am not understanding from where i have to start. Any example related this.

For more about my question details in another post.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2080284.aspx?I+need+this+type+of+jquery+sliders

Comment: Can any buddy tell me, how to achieve this requirement.@B

Comment: it's difficult to determine your own knowledge and familiarity in regards to .net web development with client-side frameworks (like jquery). The fundamental stuff is, you start with creating a web application, you add jquery (either via referencing a cdn in a link, or referencing it in your own project, which requires you to download it and put the file in your project). that's your start.

Comment: what sort of application are you working with? MVC, webform, SPA? what sort of dynamic slider control is this? (.Net WebControl, jquery control)..

Comment: I am working with web form. @BrettCaswell

Comment: okay, well first.. determine what you want returned from your ajax call, do you want the actual markup returned, or do you want data returned? that is: application/json, application/x-javascript, text/plain, text/xml, application/xml, text/html. Ajax, being a technique, actually utilizes XHR (XmlHttpRequest) objects.. for webform, I would recommend creating a GenericHandler page, or implement an IHttpHandler on an object and register it to a route.. it's typically easier to just add the generic handler page (.ashx).

Comment: Did you check this link, here he explain every thing..  https://forums.asp.net/t/2080284.aspx?I+need+this+type+of+jquery+sliders  ..@BrettCaswell

Comment: First i had used table with 10 td.. like that... <table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table> .. @BrettCaswell

Comment: What Next..@BrettCaswell

Comment: no, he doesn't really explain anything there.. you can't look at the DOM, or html output, and determine the underline mechanics, controls, and eventlisteners.. 

his suggestion to use 'web method' is reasonable. He means you should add/declare a `WebMethodAttribute` to a `method` on a `page` type, it's more in-line with WebApi controller methodology.. the framework will then do deserialization automatically... WebMethods and WebApi Attributes are all abstractions to IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest, and are less granular implementations..

Comment: Can you give me 10 points sentence, i will start my work, really i dont know, getting confuse. @BrettCaswell

Comment: This is related example, http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Price-Range-Slider-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery-Slider-plugin-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx  ..@BrettCaswell

Comment: hmm... so you have a working project you can download and you're posting an SO question under the notion that you just don't understand it?     there is no way to answer such a question.. it's inappropriate to even pose it. you should remove this question; and then, perhaps, ask someone in SO chat to help you better understand your working example. It will take a fluent conversation to help you better understand this matter, not a Q&A.